# What are the black bars beneath American Footballer's eyes are used for?

Tags: american-football

I often see football players with black bars right under their eyes.

I can't figure out a reason why they are necessary. What are they used for?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called "[Eye Black](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_black)".  It is used under the eyes of athletes to help reduce the glare of the sun and it does improve an athlete's ability to differentiate between light and dark, making it easier for a player to track moving objects in a bright environment.